# Spring-Boot PostgreSQL exception thrown trying to connect?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

I'm trying to connect in a PostgreSQL. The database already exists but it always throwns an exception that I don't know how to fix.

How could I fix this ?

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5432/db
spring.datasource.username=pgsql
spring.datasource.password=pgsql
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

**Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="usuario")
public class Usuario implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;    

    @Id
    @Column(name = "idusuario", columnDefinition = "NUMERIC", length = 20)
    private long idusuario;

    private String login;

    private String senha;

    private String nome;

    @Column(name = "ativo", columnDefinition = "NUMERIC", length = 5)
    private int ativo; //status

    public Usuario() {
        super();
    }
```

**Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface UsuarioRepository extends JpaRepository<Usuario, Long> {
}
```

**RestController**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/Usuarios")
public class UsuarioService {

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioRepository repository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/findAll", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<Usuario>> findAll() {
        List<Usuario> lista = repository.findAll();     
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(lista);
    }   

    @RequestMapping(value = "/findBy/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Usuario> findBy(@PathVariable long id) {
        List<Usuario> lista = repository.findAll();
        Usuario usuario = lista.stream()
                        .filter(u -> u.getIdusuario() == id)
                        .findFirst()
                        .orElseGet(() -> new Usuario());
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(usuario);
    }


}
```

**Exception**

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
[32m :: Spring Boot :: [39m      [2m (v2.1.4.RELEASE)[0;39m

[2m2019-04-15 18:08:30.708[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m11696[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mcom.iguana.CooperativaWsApplication     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting CooperativaWsApplication on lenovo with PID 11696 (C:\Users\Fernando\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.0.2.RELEASE\CooperativaWS\target\classes started by Fernando in C:\Users\Fernando\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.0.2.RELEASE\CooperativaWS)
[2m2019-04-15 18:08:30.710[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m11696[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mcom.iguana.CooperativaWsApplication     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
[2m2019-04-15 18:08:30.759[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m11696[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36m.e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
[2m2019-04-15 18:08:30.760[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m11696[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36m.e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor[0;39m [2m:[0;39m For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
[2m2019-04-15 18:08:31.552[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m11696[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36m.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
[2m2019-04-15 18:08:31.618[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m11696[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36m.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 59ms. Found 1 repository interfaces.
[2m2019-04-15 18:08:31.993[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m11696[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mtrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$84b0c327] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
[2m2019-04-15 18:08:32.352[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m11696[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8888 (http)
[2m2019-04-15 18:08:32.374[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m11696[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting service [Tomcat]
[2m2019-04-15 18:08:32.374[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m11696[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36morg.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.17]
[2m2019-04-15 18:08:32.483[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m11696[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
[2m2019-04-15 18:08:32.483[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m11696[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.web.context.ContextLoader           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1723 ms
[2m2019-04-15 18:08:32.682[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m11696[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Starting...
[2m2019-04-15 18:08:33.088[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m11696[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
[2m2019-04-15 18:08:33.147[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m11696[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
[2m2019-04-15 18:08:33.304[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m11696[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36morg.hibernate.Version                   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.9.Final}
[2m2019-04-15 18:08:33.305[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m11696[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36morg.hibernate.cfg.Environment           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
[2m2019-04-15 18:08:33.433[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m11696[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.hibernate.annotations.common.Version  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
[2m2019-04-15 18:08:33.564[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m11696[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36morg.hibernate.dialect.Dialect           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
[2m2019-04-15 18:09:04.316[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m11696[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36morg.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.TypeInfo  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000362: Unable to retrieve type info result set : org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
[2m2019-04-15 18:09:04.328[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m11696[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36morg.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.TypeInfo  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000362: Unable to retrieve type info result set : org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This connection has been closed.
[2m2019-04-15 18:09:04.333[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m11696[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.h.e.j.e.i.LobCreatorBuilderImpl       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl.useContextualLobCreation(LobCreatorBuilderImpl.java:113) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl.makeLobCreatorBuilder(LobCreatorBuilderImpl.java:54) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentImpl.<init>(JdbcEnvironmentImpl.java:271) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:114) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:179) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:119) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:904) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:935) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) [spring-orm-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) [spring-orm-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) [spring-orm-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) [spring-orm-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) [spring-orm-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837) [spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774) [spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) [spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) [spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) [spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) [spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at com.iguana.CooperativaWsApplication.main(CooperativaWsApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This connection has been closed.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.checkClosed(PgConnection.java:783) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.createClob(PgConnection.java:1268) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    ... 49 common frames omitted

[2m2019-04-15 18:09:04.335[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m11696[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@37d10bd5 marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08003), ErrorCode(0)

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This connection has been closed.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.checkClosed(PgConnection.java:783) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.clearWarnings(PgConnection.java:694) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.close(ProxyConnection.java:242) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.closeConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:127) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.releaseConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:185) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:125) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:179) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:119) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:904) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:935) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) [spring-orm-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) [spring-orm-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) [spring-orm-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) [spring-orm-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) [spring-orm-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837) [spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774) [spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) [spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) [spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) [spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) [spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at com.iguana.CooperativaWsApplication.main(CooperativaWsApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]

[2m2019-04-15 18:09:04.341[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m11696[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36morg.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@31bec914
[2m2019-04-15 18:09:10.741[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m11696[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mj.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
[2m2019-04-15 18:09:10.782[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m11696[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m LiveReload server is running on port 35729
[2m2019-04-15 18:09:11.150[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m11696[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
[2m2019-04-15 18:09:11.182[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m11696[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36maWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration[0;39m [2m:[0;39m spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
[2m2019-04-15 18:09:11.359[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m11696[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36m.s.s.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration[0;39m [2m:[0;39m 

Using generated security password: 053d20a8-bdb4-4fb4-a863-b52fe11c472d

[2m2019-04-15 18:09:11.446[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m11696[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Creating filter chain: any request, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@429f5f3c, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@25f660f8, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@6268cd5c, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@2db48b5, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@7e0458d4, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@533e9404, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@189121ac, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@797428da, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@621e3d2a, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@62e89bb8, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@381135d9, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@75423382, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@68790e27, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@527b5b41, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@7426a2da]
[2m2019-04-15 18:09:11.530[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m11696[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat started on port(s): 8888 (http) with context path ''
[2m2019-04-15 18:09:11.533[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m11696[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mcom.iguana.CooperativaWsApplication     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Started CooperativaWsApplication in 41.161 seconds (JVM running for 42.186)
[2m2019-04-15 18:09:28.463[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m11696[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8888-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
[2m2019-04-15 18:09:28.463[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m11696[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8888-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
[2m2019-04-15 18:09:28.472[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m11696[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8888-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Completed initialization in 9 ms
[2m2019-04-15 18:09:39.913[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m11696[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[n(10)-127.0.0.1][0;39m [36minMXBeanRegistrar$SpringApplicationAdmin[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Application shutdown requested.
[2m2019-04-15 18:09:39.917[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m11696[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[n(10)-127.0.0.1][0;39m [36mo.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
[2m2019-04-15 18:09:39.918[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m11696[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[n(10)-127.0.0.1][0;39m [36mj.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
[2m2019-04-15 18:09:39.921[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m11696[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[n(10)-127.0.0.1][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
[2m2019-04-15 18:09:39.926[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m11696[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[n(10)-127.0.0.1][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem just adding the clauses below  in `application.properties`

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
```